# Using One onclicklistener for multiple buttons(made in loop)

Tags: java, android

I am making multiple buttons using for loop and want to use one onclicklistener for all of those. The problem is that since I am making buttons in loop so dont know how to distinguish them in while loop(as i dont have different button ids). Here is the MainActivity code

```
    package com.example.practice_button_loop;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;



    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        private static final String TAG = "ZSA";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button myButton = null;

    int number = 10; // number of buttons
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttons);
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setId(i);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        myButton.findViewById(R.id.buttons);
        myButton.setText("Button# " + i);
        layout.addView(myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick:"+v.getId());
    //System.out.println(v);
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttons:
            Log.d(TAG, "on:"+v.getId());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button #" +v, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

And here is my main.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


     </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This line is the main problem I think:

```
  case R.id.buttons:
```

Comment: In you switch case, instead of checking "R.id.buttons", you could be checking the ID you assigned to each button during the loop.

Comment: This code asking for RecyclerView usage instead ...

Comment: I am new to android so can you elaborate on RecyclerView, or give some usefull links as i did saw that briefly but got confused. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the ID of the buttons layout by using the described "case" statement. You should be able to use the ID of the created button.

Replace

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick:"+v.getId());
    //System.out.println(v);
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttons:
            Log.d(TAG, "on:"+v.getId());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button #" +v, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

with

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick:"+v.getId());
    int id = v.getId();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button #" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If that doesn't work, try wrapping the button in an object that contains a method to get and set the button's "id."

Something like:

```
public class ButtonWithId {
  private final Button button;
  private final int id;

  public ButtonWithId(Button button, int id) {
    this.button = button;
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help my issue is resolved by replacing what you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you posted, you have a few options. You're assigning IDs from 1-9, so you could check for those values in your listener:

```
switch(v.getId()){
    case 1:
        Log.d(TAG, "on:"+v.getId());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button #" +v, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case 2:
        Log.d(TAG, "on:"+v.getId());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button #" +v, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    // etc
}
```

Since you know that the IDs run from 1-9, though, you might not even want to bother checking the ID:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button #" +v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Alternatively, you could set up your click listener slightly differently:

```
for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
    myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setId(i);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    myButton.findViewById(R.id.buttons);
    myButton.setText("Button# " + i);
    layout.addView(myButton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener((v) -> onButtonClick(myButton, i));
}
```

```
public void onButtonClick(Button button, int index) {
    // here you have direct access to the index
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply your solution works as well.Thanks